# Site background zoomed in on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**Scenario**

I am building a website for a client, the site works fine locally and externally on desktop but on mobile it doesn't work, the background images are extremely zoomed in. but when i use chrome devtools and change the view to mobile view everything works as expected.

Here is an image of what it should look like.

[image]

Here is an image of what it looks like.

[image]

Here is the CSS for the header element.

```
.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("../img/header-2.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Question**

Why is this happening, and why is chrome devtools showing as if everything is okay?

If you need anymore information please ask and ill provide.

**edit**

This is happening specifically on IOS devices. Everyone ive asked to test that has an IOS device has shown me the same screenshot of the image being extremely zoomed in.

Comment: do you have viewport meta tag in html? like this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Yeah i do, else the chrome view itself wouldnt work i dont think `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`

Comment: The first and second image differ by a clear mile! Everything is zoomed in; not just the background. I suggest you go over the `CSS` and use `media queries` to ensure the website looks good regardless of screen size.

Comment: yes do as @AngelPolitis said or share a fiddle of that page with us.

Comment: @RajnishCoder ill try get a fiddle up or would a direct web link be better?

Comment: sure web page will be better.

Comment: paul.ikdevelopment.co.uk

Comment: On my phone, using the Chrome browser, the website looks like the first image @KenziieeFlavius.

Comment: @AngelPolitis what phone are you using? Im using an iPhone SE

Comment: the website looks fine as creative. (firefox and chrome both), and code is also fine.

Comment: @RajnishCoder are these both on your mobile device?

Comment: I checked in Moto g4 plus (firefox, chrome) and in my laptop in both browsers and browser emulator too, it works fine.

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/gnRXyJF.jpg) is how the webpage looks on my phone @KenziieeFlavius.

Comment: @RajnishCoder im wondering if its just on iPhones because both me and my friend tested on iphones and got the same result

Comment: @AngelPolitis just got a couple more people to test and it seems like its an IOS specific problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .header {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has not fixed the problem for me

Comment: I've tried this without the media query and its fixed the problem, but the image moves extremely slowly while its parralaxed